# Get last published post in Wordpress using wp-cli

Tags: wp-cli

I'm using below `wp-cli` command to get latest post ID:

`wp post list --order='DESC' --orderby='ID' --field='ID' | head -1`

This, however is inefficient as all posts are retrieved from DB and then `head` limits the number of returned posts.

Is there a way to limit the number of returned posts using [wp query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add:

```
--posts_per_page=1
```

to limit the queried items to a single item.